# Solving PDE with method of characteristcs with both initial conditions $0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I need to solve using the method of characteristics:
$$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
$$u(x,0)=0, \hspace{2cm} u(0,t)=h(t)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0) = 0, \hspace{2cm} u(L,t) = 0$$
I'm at a loss how to do this. Normally, you would extend the inital conditions as odd or even periodic functions and proceed from there. But now both the initial conditions are $0$. If you say that $u(x,t) = F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$, then you'd find only zero as a solution. I get that this is not correct since $h(t)$, the boundary condition at $0$, is constantly "making" waves which are being reflected at the fixed end $L$. So how should I solve this then?

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to draw a picture. Every characteristic line that starts at $t=0$, $x>0$ will carry the information $u=0$. Now draw characteristic lines starting at $x=0$. The characteristics starting here at time $t_0$ will carry the information $u(x,t) = h(t_0)$. What remains to be done is given a point $(x,t)$, determine if it came from that line and how to deal with reflections, which more or less follows the standard methods.

Comment: @whpowell96 Could you elaborate? I don't immediately see how to obtain the solution from "more or less the standard methods".

Comment: You handle the reflections the same way you handle them in the case you described, except the data that is carried along the characteristics comes from the boundary condition $h(t)$ instead of the initial conditions